# Javascript DOM Selector

Tags: javascript

I am learning JS and thought I had an ok grasp on it, until I finally reached the end of the line trying to work this one out. I have looked through the js reference and tried to debug myself, but I can't see where I am going wrong.

I basically want the alert to show the href from the links when pressed left or right, I don't need anyone to hold my hand, but a little friendly hint at where I am going wrong would really help.

Many thanks.

The HTML:

```
<nav class="portfolio-navigation clearfix col-sm-2">
   <div class="portfolio-prev">
       <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" class="tooltip-shortcode mt-tooltip" data-placement="top" title="#">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-next">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" class="tooltip-shortcode mt-tooltip" data-placement="top" title="#">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

THE JS (With two seperate attempts):

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || event;
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37: 
            var linkprev = getElementsByClassName('portfolio-navigation')[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML;
            alert(linkprev);
            break;
        case 38: alert(window.location.href); break;
        case 39: 
            var linknext = getElementsByClassName('portfolio-next')[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute("href");
            alert(linknext);
            break;
        case 40: alert('down the drain'); break;        
    }
};
```

Comment: And what *is* it that you feel is 'going wrong'; what's the error that you want help with?

Comment: It will not alert the innerHTML or href when left or right arrow keys are pressed, it will alert a string on arrow down but nothing when I use the dom selectors.

Comment: Don't you need `document.getElementsByClassName`? This should have shown up as a console error, did it?

Comment: `var linkprev = getElementsByClassName('portfolio-navigation')` should be `var linkprev = document.getElementsByClassName('portfolio-navigation')`. Same for the other one too. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6e2zbhgk/)

Comment: ...you would be greatly helped by observing the errors in your browser's developer console.

Comment: Thank you for all the reply's, I was using scratch pad to test out this func and it did not throw any errors. I will for sure keep an eye on the console, thx for the tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
document.getElementsByClassName
```

You were missing the **`document.`** part.
This would have shown up as a console error if you were watching that.

But easier to just do

```
document.querySelector('.portfolio-navigation a')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so in theory this should work, because for me it does not: 'document.getElementsByClassName('portfolio-navigation')[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href;'